# How to run client and server UDP listeners on the same machine

Tags: c#, networking, udp, udpclient

Both client and server send and receive on a given port. In production they are on separate machines and there is no problem. In development it would be a great deal more convenient to run them on the same machine and avoid the need for deployment and setting up and tearing down a remote debug session.

I tried this

```
var uc = new UdpClient();
var ep = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
uc.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
uc.Client.Bind(ep);
```

and it doesn't *barf* but I still can't bind multiple listeners to the same endpoint. After the fact I discovered that ExclusiveAddressUse defaults to false anyhow so this approach produces nothing but extra code.

Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously cant use the same port on the same machine, just use an [#if directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-if) for `debug` and change your ports accordingly

The following might help

**Client**

```
#if DEBUG
    uc client = new UdpClient(34534);
#else
    uc client = new UdpClient();
#endif
```

[UdpClient Constructor (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35e07es2(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Initializes a new instance of the UdpClient class and binds it to the
>   local port number provided.

**Remarks**

> This constructor creates an underlying Socket and binds it to the port
>   number from which you intend to communicate. **Use this constructor if
>   you are only interested in setting the local port number**. The
>   underlying service provider will assign the local IP address. If you
>   pass 0 to the constructor, the underlying service provider will assign
>   a port number. If this constructor is used, the UdpClient instance is
>   set with an address family of IPv4 that cannot be changed or
>   overwritten by a connect method call with an IPv6 target.

**Disclaimer**, totally untested, just read the documentation, possibly wrong :)

Comment: Funnily enough I found the answer in my own answer to another question long ago.  Directives won't sort it out, the problem is you can have at most one _listener_ per endpoint. You can have multiple _sockets_ bound to one address/port pair, because a connection is identified by two endpoints, but a listener only has one endpoint so you can only have one _listener_ socket per endpoint. I knew this, but I didn't want to know it because it's a damn nuisance.

Comment: @PeterWone computers suck, glad you figured it out

Comment: @PeterWone you might want to consider answering your own question

Comment: Have the win. Someone may as well have some joy of it!